# How exactly does random.random() work in python?

Tags: python, random

I am a bit confused about how the random.random() function works in python.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.random) say that it 'Return the next random floating point number in the range [0.0, 1.0)'. 
I understand that pseudo-random number generators work by performing some operation on a value. Generally this value is the previous number generated by the generator. So I think that's what **'next random floating point'** means here. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

But when I saw the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/random.py) of the random library, random function is not defined in the `class Random`. Instead, its defined in the `class SystemRandom` as follows (line 671 of the code):

```
 def random(self):
        """Get the next random number in the range [0.0, 1.0)."""
        return (int.from_bytes(_urandom(7), 'big') >> 3) * RECIP_BPF
```

If I understand this correctly, this function generates a random number using os.urandom. Which, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.urandom), returns random bytes from an OS-specific randomness source. So this will not give the 'next' floating point random number.

How are the two connected? or are they two different things?

I am quite confused here. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`random.random()` is actually defined [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/random.py#l744):

```
random = _inst.random
```

However, it is just a reference to C implementation.

Here is a quote from the source:

> General notes on the underlying Mersenne Twister core generator:
>
> - The period is 2**19937-1.
> - It is one of the most extensively tested generators in existence.
> - The random() method is implemented in C, executes in a single Python step,   and is, therefore, threadsafe.

You probably want to look at the article on [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister). To speak briefly, the state of the generator is not the same as "previous number", it is much more complicated thing. So you are wrong in «…pseudo-random number generators work by performing some operation on a value. Generally this value is the previous number generated by the generator».

As for `SystemRandom.random()`, it is in a way unrelated to `random.random()`. It is possible in Python that function with the same name imported from different modules are different, so you can't rely on function's name here.

Comment: Do you know where one could find the C module?

Answer (score 22):

The `random` module in python contains two interfaces(classes) of [pseudorandom number generators(PRNGs)](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator). You can view it as two ways to generate random numbers.

- **Random** uses the [Mersenne Twister PRNG](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister). It is **not** cryptographically secure
- **SystemRandom** uses either the [/dev/urandom](https://wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) file on [POSIX](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) systems or the [CryptGenRandom()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom) function on [Windows NT](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT) systems. Both are [Cryptographically secure PRNGs](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator).

---

> **A note on the module** `secrets`.
>
> The module `secrets` does **not** implement any type of [PRNG](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) but provides helper functions(which is awesome because we don't have to write them ourselves) based on SystemRandom and os.urandom(which SystemRandom is based upon). The comments are mine:
>
> ```
> from random import SystemRandom
> _sysrand = SystemRandom() #secrets._sysrand
> randbits = _sysrand.getrandbits #secrets.randbits
> choice = _sysrand.choice #secrets.choice
>
> def randbelow(exclusive_upper_bound): #secrets.randbelow
>     ...
>     return _sysrand._randbelow(exclusive_upper_bound) #uses SystemRandom
>
> def token_bytes(nbytes=None): #secrets.token_bytes
>     ...
>     return os.urandom(nbytes)
>
> def token_hex(nbytes=None): #secrets.token_hex(uses token_bytes())
>     ...
>     return binascii.hexlify(token_bytes(nbytes)).decode('ascii')
>
> def token_urlsafe(nbytes=None): # secrets.token_urlsafe(uses token_bytes())
>     ...
>     tok = token_bytes(nbytes)
>     return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(tok).rstrip(b'=').decode('ascii')
> ```

### How does Random.random() work?

random.random() is defined in the 'random.py' module on line 749(for me)

```
_inst = Random()
...
random = _inst.random
```

The class `random.Random()` does not define the `random()` method per se but inherits `_random.Random()`(which does define a method called `random()`), which is a class called `Random()` located at the module `_random`.

The `C` source code of the `_random`(it is a built-in module) module can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Modules/_randommodule.c)(it is actually called `_randommodule.c`. See explanation below)

> ### [Naming convention for python modules written in C/C++](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example)
>
> (Historically, if a module is called spam, the C file containing its
>   implementation is called spammodule.c; if the module name is very
>   long, like spammify, the module name can be just spammify.c.)

The `_random.Random.random()`(or `random.random()`) method is defined as `_random_Random_random_impl()` in the `_randommodule.c` file.

```
static PyObject *
_random_Random_random_impl(RandomObject *self)
{
    uint32_t a=genrand_int32(self)>>5, b=genrand_int32(self)>>6;
    return PyFloat_FromDouble((a*67108864.0+b)*(1.0/9007199254740992.0));
}
```

`genrand_int32()` is a function defined by the [Mersenne Twister PRNG](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) implementation which returns a 4-byte number.

### How does SystemRandom().random() work?

**(I know you didn't ask for SystemRandom(), but at the time I wrote this I hadn't realized)**

I've made this image as an overview of my answer(However, I do encourage you to read it all)

[image: Overview of SystemRandom's random() method]

`SystemRandom().random()` is defined in the module `random.py`.

```
 ...
 def random(self):
    """Get the next random number in the range [0.0, 1.0)."""
    return (int.from_bytes(_urandom(7), 'big') >> 3) * RECIP_BPF**strong text**
```

The function uses another function called urandom() defined in the module `os.py`

```
from os import urandom as _urandom
```

The `os.py` module does not define the function `urandom()` itself but imports it from a built-in module. `os.py` will import the `posix` built-in module if you are on a  [POSIX OS](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) or the `nt` built-in module if you are on a [Windows NT OS](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT). These modules contain the definition for urandom().

```
if 'posix' in _names:
    name = 'posix'
    linesep = '\n'
    from posix import *
```

OR

```
elif 'nt' in _names:
    name = 'nt'
    linesep = '\r\n'
    from nt import *
```

> `posix` and `nt` are built-in modules, so they don't have the
>   `__file__` attribute.

### Diving in the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython):

### POSIX

> - `urandom()` is defined in the `posixmodule.c` as [os_urandom_impl()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7f41c8e0dd237d1f3f0a1d2ba2f3ee4e4bd400a7/Modules/posixmodule.c#L11973) which calls [_PyOS_URandom()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/331a6a56e9a9c72f3e4605987fabdaec72677702/Python/bootstrap_hash.c#L520).

```
static PyObject *
os_urandom_impl(PyObject *module, Py_ssize_t size)
{
  ...
  bytes = PyBytes_FromStringAndSize(NULL, size);
  ...
  result = _PyOS_URandom(PyBytes_AS_STRING(bytes), PyBytes_GET_SIZE(bytes));
  ...
  return bytes
}
```

> - `_PyOS_URandom()` is defined in the `bootstrap_hash.c` file which then calls [pyurandom()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/331a6a56e9a9c72f3e4605987fabdaec72677702/Python/bootstrap_hash.c#L478)

```
int
_PyOS_URandom(void *buffer, Py_ssize_t size)
{
    return pyurandom(buffer, size, 1, 1);
}
```

> - `pyurandom()` is defined in the `bootstrap_hash.c` file which then calls [dev_urandom()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/331a6a56e9a9c72f3e4605987fabdaec72677702/Python/bootstrap_hash.c#L305).

```
static int
pyurandom(void *buffer, Py_ssize_t size, int blocking, int raise)
{
  ...
  return dev_urandom(buffer, size, raise);
  ...
}
```

> - `dev_urandom` is defined in the `bootstrap_hash.c` file which then uses the `/dev/urandom` directory to get random bytes.

```
static int
dev_urandom(char *buffer, Py_ssize_t size, int raise)
{
  ...
  fd = _Py_open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);
  ...
  do {
    n = _Py_read(fd, buffer, (size_t)size);
    ...
  } while (0 < size);
  ...
}
```

### Windows NT

> It may look a bit weird(I thought that as well) but the `posixmodule.c` file is also used for the NT systems, here is a quote(comment) from the beginning of the file
>
> **This file is also used for Windows NT/MS-Win.  In that case the
>
>   module actually calls itself 'nt', not 'posix', and a few    functions
>   are either unimplemented or implemented differently.  The source
>
>   assumes that for Windows NT, the macro 'MS_WINDOWS' is defined
>   independent    of the compiler used.  Different compilers define their
>   own feature    test macro, e.g. '_MSC_VER'.**

For Windows NT the function call chain is the same as for POSIX until the pyurandom() function

> - `pyurandom()` is defined in the `bootstrap_hash.c` file which then calls [win32_urandom()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/331a6a56e9a9c72f3e4605987fabdaec72677702/Python/bootstrap_hash.c#L56).

```
static int
pyurandom(void *buffer, Py_ssize_t size, int blocking, int raise)
{
  ...
  #ifdef MS_WINDOWS
      return win32_urandom((unsigned char *)buffer, size, raise);
  #else
  ...
}
```

> - `win32_urandom()` is defined in the `bootstrap_hash.c` file which then calls `CryptGenRandom()`.

```
static int
win32_urandom(unsigned char *buffer, Py_ssize_t size, int raise)
{
  ...
  if (!CryptGenRandom(hCryptProv, chunk, buffer))
  {
  ...
  }
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

> - `CryptGenRandom()` is declared in the `wincrypt.h` file and defined in the `Advapi32.lib` and `Advapi32.dll` libraries(These files are provided by Microsoft)

Answer (score 1):

This is the fragment you missed (CPython32):

```
import _random

class Random(_random.Random):
```

where the `_random.Random` class is

```
>>> import _random
>>> dir(_random.Random)
[(...) 'getrandbits', 'getstate', 'jumpahead', 'random', 'seed', 'setstate']
```

and, from docstring at the beginning of the same random.py implementation file

> General notes on the underlying Mersenne Twister core generator:
>
> - The period is 2**19937-1.
> - It is one of the most extensively tested generators in existence.
> - **The random() method is implemented in C, executes in a single Python step,
>   and is, therefore, threadsafe.**

The _random is a compiled C library that contains few basic operations, which are further extended in Python's implementation contained at random.py file.

Answer (score 0):

you are correct this is using os.urandom function as

```
from os import urandom as _urandom

BPF = 53        # Number of bits in a float
RECIP_BPF = 2**-BPF

def random():
    """Get the next random number in the range [0.0, 1.0)."""
    return (int.from_bytes(_urandom(7), 'big') >> 3) * RECIP_BPF

print(random())
print(RECIP_BPF)
print(int.from_bytes(_urandom(7), 'big')>> 3)
print(int.from_bytes(_urandom(7), 'little') >> 3)
```

play with it and you will get it properly.

Comment: You have my upvote, although 53 is not number of bits in a float. It is number of bits in float64 i.e. double used to contain mantisa. Exponent is here ignored. Therefore calling variable BPF is also a bit dubious. But we can skip over such details because Python is always using doubles for his floats  unless "explicitly ordered" not to by using ctypes.c_float() or numpy.float(). But say that 53 is number of bits in the float(64) is simply wrong. It's just mantisa.

Comment: Using 2**-53 as a maximal reciprocal (1.0/2**53) to turn int into Python float ranging from 0 to 1 does the trick though. Well, shifting does its part as well. :D

Comment: Yeah I know I also had doubt over 53 as bits in float but as it was defined in the random py itself thought to give it benefit of doubt cause it works correctly and in python float and double aren't that different at least as much as I have used.

Comment: thats why made sure to mention the exact comment present in the random py for BPF definition.